# Cron was set to Insert data into a table every 5 minutes using crontab, but only insert at the hour (1:00) not every 5 minutes as expected

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, cron, database-administration

This script is to insert Wind data from a weather station. The data comes from this text file online. The weather station reports and update its text file every 5 minutes.
http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/data/realtime2/IMGP4.txt

Crontab was set  to run every five minutes, but is only inserting data every hour. As a testing mode We changed crontab to run every :15 minutes and It is doing this. Lets assume it ran a t 1:15. The past data from 1:00, 1:05, 1:10 and 1:15 gets inserted on the table, and it will stop inserting new data (nothing at 1:30, 1:45, 2:00) until next hour Will run again at 2:15, and will do the same (insert the past data 2:00, 2:05, 2:10 and 2:15).

Example of the data

```
    #YY  MM DD hh mm WDIR WSPD GST  WVHT   DPD   APD MWD   PRES  ATMP  WTMP  DEWP  VIS PTDY  TIDE
    2015 07 13 17 20 120  7.7 11.3    MM    MM    MM  MM 1016.0  29.9    MM    MM   MM   MM    MM
    2015 07 13 17 15 120  7.7 11.8    MM    MM    MM  MM 1016.0  29.8    MM    MM   MM   MM    MM
    2015 07 13 17 10 110  7.7 11.8    MM    MM    MM  MM 1016.0  29.7    MM    MM   MM   MM    MM                   
    2015 07 13 17 05 110  7.2 11.3    MM    MM    MM  MM 1016.0  29.7    MM    MM   MM   MM    MM                   
    2015 07 13 17 00 120  7.7 11.8    MM    MM    MM  MM 1016.0  29.6    MM    MM   MM -0.8    MM
```

The logs reveal the problem is in these lines:

```
        $date = $realvalues[0]."-".$realvalues[1]."-".$realvalues[2];
        $time = $realvalues[3].":".$realvalues[4].":00";
        $wdir = str_replace('MM','',$realvalues[5]);
        $spd = str_replace('MM','',$realvalues[6])*1.94384449;
        $gust = str_replace('MM','',$realvalues[7])*1.94384449;
        $atem = str_replace('MM','',$realvalues[14]);
        $timeval = gmmktime($realvalues[3],$realvalues[4],"00",$realvalues[1],$realvalues[2],$realvalues[0]);
        //echo $timeval." <= ".$timemax.'<br>';$control++;
        if($timeval <= $timemax){unset($realvalues);continue;}
        //echo $realvalues[3].",".$realvalues[4].","."00".",".$realvalues[1].",".$realvalues[2].",".$realvalues[0].'<br>';
        //echo $info2['MAX(date)']." == ".$date." && ".$maxTime[0]."==".$realvalues[3]." && ".$maxTime[1]."==".$realvalues[4]."<br/>";
        if($info2['MAX(date)']<$date){
            $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO `ndbc` (`station_id`,`date`,`time`,`Wind Direction (-4m)`,`Wind Speed (-4m)`,`Air Temperature (-3m)`,`Wind Gust (-4m)`) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')",$info['id'], $date, $time, $wdir, $spd, $atem, $gust);echo $query.'<br/>';//die();
            mysql_query($query);
```

Create Table Script:

```
        <?php 
        require_once("../connections/connection_index.php");
        function getData($id, &$xdata, &$ydata, &$dirdata, &$yesterday,     &$future, &$realStation, &$xdata2, &$ydata2, &$dirdata2, &$gust, &$gust2){  
    $query = sprintf("SELECT `type`,`wind station relation`,`wind platform relation`,`name`,`platform` FROM `stations` WHERE id = '".$id."'");//echo $query;die();
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $info = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $realStation = $info['name'];   
    $now_datetime = gmdate("Y-m-d H:00:00");
    $val = explode(' ',$now_datetime);
    $time = explode(':',$val[1]);
    $date = explode('-',$val[0]);
    $timestamp = gmmktime($time[0], 0, 0, $date[1], $date[2], $date[0]);
    $yesterday = $timestamp-3600*16;
    $future = $timestamp;//+3600*18;
    $old_datetime = gmdate("Y-m-d H:00:00",$yesterday);
    $old_val = explode(' ',$old_datetime);
    $future_datetime = gmdate("Y-m-d H:00:00",$future);
    $future_val = explode(' ',$future_datetime);
    $query = sprintf("SELECT `date`,`time`,`Wind Speed (-4m)`,`Wind         Direction (-4m)`,`Wind Gust (-4m)` FROM `".$info['platform']."` WHERE station_id = '".$id."' AND date BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s'",$old_val[0],$future_val[0]);//echo $query;die();
    $result2 = mysql_query($query);
    while($info2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)){
        $time = explode(':',$info2['time']);
        $date = explode('-',$info2['date']);
        $timestamp = gmmktime($time[0], 0, 0, $date[1], $date[2], $date[0]);
        if($info['type']=='observation'){
            $xdata[]= $timestamp-3600*4;
            $ydata[]= $info2['Wind Speed (-4m)'];
            $dirdata[]= $info2['Wind Direction (-4m)'];
            $gust[]= $info2['Wind Gust (-4m)'];
        }
        else{
            $xdata2[]= $timestamp-3600*4;
            $ydata2[]= $info2['Wind Speed (-4m)'];
            $dirdata2[]= $info2['Wind Direction (-4m)'];
            $gust2[]= $info2['Wind Gust (-4m)'];
        }
    }
    if(!empty($info['wind station relation']) && !empty($info['wind station relation'])){
        if($info['type']=='observation'){
            $type='forecast';
        }
        else{
            $type='observation';
        }
        $query = sprintf("SELECT `id` FROM `stations` WHERE `code` = '".$info['wind station relation']."' AND type = '".$type."'");//echo $query;die();
        $result3 = mysql_query($query);
        $info3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3);
        $query = sprintf("SELECT `date`,`time`,`Wind Speed (-4m)`,`Wind Direction (-4m)` FROM `".$info['wind platform relation']."` WHERE station_id = '".$info3['id']."' AND date BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s'",$old_val[0],$future_val[0]);//echo $query;die();
        $result3 = mysql_query($query);
        while($info3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3)){
            $time = explode(':',$info3['time']);
            $date = explode('-',$info3['date']);
            $timestamp = gmmktime($time[0], 0, 0, $date[1], $date[2], $date[0]);
            if($type=='observation'){
                $xdata[]= $timestamp-3600*4;
                $ydata[]= $info3['Wind Speed (-4m)'];
                $dirdata[]= $info3['Wind Direction (-4m)'];
                $gust[]= $info3['Wind Gust (-4m)'];
            }
            else{
                $xdata2[]= $timestamp-3600*4;
                $ydata2[]= $info3['Wind Speed (-4m)'];
                $dirdata2[]= $info3['Wind Direction (-4m)'];
                $gust2[]= $info3['Wind Gust (-4m)'];
            }
        }
    }
        }
        function cmp($a, $b) {
        return strcmp($a[0], $b[0]);
        }
       function getticks(&$Ticks,$yesterday,$future){
    $value=$yesterday;
    $i=0;
    $Ticks=array();
    while($value<=$future){
        $Ticks[$i]=$value;
        $value=$value+3600;
        $i++;
    }
}

        $station=$_GET["ID"];
        $numOfValues=12;
          getData($station,$xdata,$ydata,$dirdata,$yesterday,$future,$realStation,$xdata2,$ydata2,$dirdata2,$gust,$gust2);
        getticks($Ticks,$yesterday,$future);
        $observation = array(array());
        $j=0;
        foreach($xdata as $x){
        $i=0;
        $observation[$j][$i]=$x;
        $i++;
        $observation[$j][$i]=$ydata[$j];
        $i++;
        $observation[$j][$i]=$dirdata[$j];
        $i++;
        $observation[$j][$i]=$gust[$j];
       $j++;
       }
       usort($observation, "cmp");
       $realxData = array();
       $realyData = array();
       $realdirData = array();
       $realgustData = array();
       $j=0;
       $TestVar=false;
       foreach($observation as $real){
       if($TestVar && $real[0]!=$realxData[$j-1]){
        $realxData[$j]=$real[0];
        $realyData[$j]=number_format($real[1],1);
        $realdirData[$j]=(int)($real[2]);
        $realgustData[$j]=$real[3];
        $j++;}
        if($yesterday<=$real[0] && $TestVar==false){
        $realxData[$j]=$real[0];
        $realyData[$j]=number_format($real[1],1);
        $realdirData[$j]=(int)($real[2]);
        $realgustData[$j]=$real[3];
        $j++;
        $TestVar=true;}
     }
       if(count($realxData)>12){
    array_splice($realxData,0,1);
    array_splice($realyData,0,1);
    array_splice($realdirData,0,1);
    array_splice($realgustData,0,1);
    /*unset($realxData[0]);
    unset($realyData[0]);
    unset($realdirData[0]);*/
 }
         /*$last_time=$real[0];
        $forecast = array(array());
        $j=0;
        foreach($xdata2 as $x){
        $i=0;
  $forecast[$j][$i]=$x;
  $i++;
  $forecast[$j][$i]=$ydata2[$j];
  $i++;
  $forecast[$j][$i]=$dirdata2[$j];
    $i++;
  $forecast[$j][$i]=$gust2[$j];
  $j++;
}
usort($forecast, "cmp");
$realxData2 = array();
$realyData2 = array();
$realdirData2 = array();
$realgustData2 = array();
$j=0;
$TestVar=false;
foreach($forecast as $real){
         if($last_time < $real[0]){
          if($TestVar && $real[0]!=$realxData2[$j-1]){
            $realxData2[$j]=$real[0];
            $realyData2[$j]=number_format($real[1],1);
            $realdirData2[$j]=(int)($real[2]);
            $realgustData2[$j]=$real[3];
            $j++;}
        if($yesterday<=$real[0] && $TestVar==false){
            $realxData2[$j]=$real[0];
            $realyData2[$j]=number_format($real[1],1);
            $realdirData2[$j]=(int)($real[2]);
            $realgustData2[$j]=$real[3];
            $j++;
            $TestVar=true;}
    }
}*/
/*echo '<pre> OBSERVATION X: '; print_r($realxData); echo '</pre>';
echo '<pre> OBSERVATION Y: '; print_r($realyData); echo '</pre>';
echo '<pre> OBSERVATION DIR: '; print_r($realdirData); echo '</pre>';
echo '<pre> OBSERVATION Gust: '; print_r($realgustData); echo '</pre>';
echo '<pre> FORECAST X: '; print_r($realxData2); echo '</pre>';
echo '<pre> FORECAST Y: '; print_r($realyData2); echo '</pre>';
echo '<pre> FORECAST DIR: '; print_r($realdirData2); echo '</pre>';
echo '<pre> FORECAST gust: '; print_r($realgustData2); echo '</pre>';
die();*/
mysql_close($connection);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Table</title>
<style type="text/css">
#data_type{
    background-color:#87AFC7;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px; 
}
        #legend{
        background-color:#CCC;
        text-align:center;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:larger;
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px; 
}
#name{
    background-color:#CCC;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px; 
}
#dates{
    background-color:#CCC;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
#hours{
    background-color:#BDBDBD;
    text-align:center;
    width:70px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
#data_ob{
    background-color: #9F3;
    text-align:center;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
#data_fore{
    background-color: #0F9;
    text-align:center;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table cellspacing="1"  style="margin:auto;">
    <tr>
    <td id="data_type">Legend:</td>
    <td id="legend" colspan="<?php echo $numOfValues ?>"><span style="background-color: #9F3;">&#160;Observation&#160;</span>
    <!--&#160;|&#160;
    <span style="background-color: #0F9;">&#160;Forecast&#160;</span>
    <span><img src="/app/elmer_test/icon.png" width="24" height="24"/>Missing Data</span>--></td>
    </tr><tr>
  <?php
    echo "<td id=\"data_type\">Name:</td>";
    echo "<td id=\"name\" colspan=\"".$numOfValues."\">".$realStation."</td>";
    ?>
  </tr><tr>
  <?php 
    //create days
    echo "<td id=\"data_type\">Date:</td>";
    $control=0;
    $time=$yesterday;
    $day=gmdate("d",$time);
    //observation
    foreach($realxData as $time){
        if(gmdate("d",$time) == $day){
            $control++;
        }
        else{
            echo "<td id=\"dates\" colspan=\"".$control."\"><div style=\"width:80px; margin:auto;\">".gmdate("Y-m-d",$time-3600)."</div></td>";
            $last_day=gmdate("d",$time-3600);
            $control=1;         
        }
        $day = gmdate("d",$time);
    }
    //new   
    if($control!=0){
        //$control++;
        echo "<td id=\"dates\" colspan=\"".$control."\"><div style=\"width:90px; margin:auto;\">".gmdate("Y-m-d",$time)."</div></td>";
    }
    //forecast
    /*$control2=0;
    $store_time=$time;
    foreach($realxData2 as $time){
        if($control2==0){
            if(gmdate("d",$time) != $day){
                echo "<td id=\"dates\" colspan=\"".$control."\">".gmdate("Y-m-d",$store_time)."</td>";
                $last_day=gmdate("d",$store_time);
                $control=0;     
            }
            $control2=1;
            $day = gmdate("d",$time);
        }
        if(gmdate("d",$time) == $day){
            $control++;
        }
        else{
            echo "<td id=\"dates\" colspan=\"".$control."\">".gmdate("Y-m-d",$time-3600*3)."</td>";
            $last_day=gmdate("d",$time-3600*3);
            $control=0;         
        }
        $day = gmdate("d",$time);           
    }           
    $control++;
    if($last_day != $day){
        echo "<td id=\"dates\" colspan=\"".$control."\">".gmdate("Y-m-d",$time)."</td>";
    }*/
    ?>
  </tr><tr>
  <?php 
    echo "<td id=\"data_type\">Time: (Local PR):</td>";
    //create observation hours
    $control=0;
    foreach($realxData as $time){
        echo "<td id=\"hours\">".gmdate("H",$time)."</td>";
        $control++;
    }
    //create forecast hours
    /*$control=0;
    foreach($realxData2 as $time){
        echo "<td id=\"hours\">".gmdate("H",$time)."</td>";
        $control++;
    }*/
    ?>
  </tr><tr>
  <?php
    //create observation data
    echo "<td id=\"data_type\">Wind Speed (kt):</td>";
    $control=0;
    foreach($realxData as $time){
            echo "<td id=\"data_ob\">".$realyData[$control]."</td>";
        $control++;
    }
    //create forecast data
    /*$control=0;
    foreach($realxData2 as $time){
        echo "<td id=\"data_fore\">".$realyData2[$control]."</td>";
        $control++;
    }*/
    ?>
  </tr><tr>
  <?php
    //create observation direction
    echo "<td id=\"data_type\">Wind Direction (deg):</td>";
    $control=0;
    foreach($realxData as $time){       
        echo "<td id=\"data_ob\">".$realdirData[$control]."</td>";
        $control++;
    }
    //create forecast direction
    /*$control=0;
    foreach($realxData2 as $time){
        echo "<td id=\"data_fore\">".$realdirData2[$control]."</td>";
        $control++;
    }*/
    ?>
  </tr><tr>
  <?php
    //create observation vector
    echo "<td id=\"data_type\">Wind Vector:</td>";
    $control=0;
    foreach($realxData as $time){
        if($realdirData[$control]<=360 && $realdirData[$control]>=0){
            if(((($realdirData[$control])+180)%360)<10){
                echo "<td id=\"data_ob\"><img src=\"/app/elmer_test/new_red_arrow/s0".((($realdirData[$control])+180)%360).".png\"/></td>";
            }
            else{
                echo "<td id=\"data_ob\"><img src=\"/app/elmer_test/new_red_arrow/s".((($realdirData[$control])+180)%360).".png\"/></td>";
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "<td id=\"data_ob\"><img src=\"/app/elmer_test/icon.png\" width=\"24\" height=\"24\"/></td>";
        }
        $control++;
    }
    //create forecast vector
    /*$control=0;
    foreach($realxData2 as $time){
        if($realdirData2[$control]<=360 && $realdirData2[$control]>=0){
            if(((($realdirData2[$control])+180)%360)<10){
                echo "<td id=\"data_fore\"><img src=\"/app/elmer_test/new_red_arrow/s0".((($realdirData2[$control])+180)%360).".png\"/></td>";
            }
            else{
                echo "<td id=\"data_fore\"><img src=\"/app/elmer_test/new_red_arrow/s".((($realdirData2[$control])+180)%360).".png\"/></td>";
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "<td id=\"data_fore\"><img src=\"/app/elmer_test/icon.png\" width=\"24\" height=\"24\"/></td>";
        }
        $control++;
    }*/
    ?>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

It does insert data at the 1:00 "whole" Hour correctly. But does not insert data every five minutes (1:05, 1:10, 1:15...... I get this Log.
Undefined variable: realvalues in /insert/ndbc.php on line 43 - 49

```
    43  $date = $realvalues[0]."-".$realvalues[1]."-".$realvalues[2];
        $time = $realvalues[3].":".$realvalues[4].":00";
        $wdir = str_replace('MM','',$realvalues[5]);
        $spd = str_replace('MM','',$realvalues[6])*1.94384449;
        $gust = str_replace('MM','',$realvalues[7])*1.94384449;
        $atem = str_replace('MM','',$realvalues[14]);
        $timeval = gmmktime($realvalues[3],$realvalues[4],"00",$realvalues[1],$realvalues[2],$realvalues[0]);
        //echo $timeval." <= ".$timemax.'<br>';$control++;
        if($timeval <= $timemax){unset($realvalues);continue;}
        //echo $realvalues[3].",".$realvalues[4].","."00".",".$realvalues[1].",".$realvalues[2].",".$realvalues[0].'<br>';
        //echo $info2['MAX(date)']." == ".$date." && ".$maxTime[0]."==".$realvalues[3]." && ".$maxTime[1]."==".$realvalues[4]."<br/>";
        if($info2['MAX(date)']<$date){
            $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO `ndbc` (`station_id`,`date`,`time`,`Wind Direction (-4m)`,`Wind Speed (-4m)`,`Air Temperature (-3m)`,`Wind Gust (-4m)`) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')",$info['id'], $date, $time, $wdir, $spd, $atem, $gust);echo $query.'<br/>';//die();
            mysql_query($query);
            unset($realvalues);
            continue;
```

Comment: Try offering some explanation instead of just a blast of code.  Some context, some traces, error messages if any, etc may help someone examine the code.

Comment: What OS are you using with Php?

Comment: Is running in Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: Edit your question and add the `CREATE TABLE` script and 2 rows of lines of the .txt file.

Comment: Also, fix your indentation...

Comment: Add your `ndbc CREATE TABLE` script from `INSERT INTO `ndbc` (`station_id`,`date`,`time`,`Wind Direction (-4m)`,`Wind Speed (-4m)`,`Air Temperature (-3m)`,`Wind Gust (-4m)`)`.

Comment: Add some error checking, otherwise this is going to be a wild goose chase.  http://php.net/mysql_error

Answer (score 0):

You can run code for every five minute. And for this you need to modify Crontab file to

```
* * * * *  /scriptpage.php
```

Comment: Cron was set to every 5 minutes but, still inserting data only at :00 minutes and skipping the 5 minutes :05, :10 :15, :20......

Comment: It does insert data at the 1:00 Hour correctly. But every five minutes (1:05, 1:10, 1:15...... I get this Log.
Undefined variable: realvalues in /insert/ndbc.php on line 43 - 49

Answer (score 0):

Runnig a job every 5 minutes in cron:

*/5 * * * * /path/to/script.php

Comment: Cron was correctly set to run every 5 minutes but, still inserting data only at :00 minutes and skipping the 5 minutes :05, :10 :15, :20...... –I get this Log. Undefined variable: realvalues in /insert/ndbc.php on line 43 - 49